# Django - Handle update form submition trigerred from admin section

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have articles that I manage via the admin section of Django.

My problem here is that I need to modify a field right after the administrator submited the form before it goes into database.

My specific need is to replace a part of a string with something else, but I don't know how to handle admin form submittions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.title = 'someStuff' #Example
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is the function to place under the model class. As simple as that